# Show negativ bars as red and positive as green with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I try to change the colors of the bars in a bar chart where the negative bars should be red and the positive ones green. I calculate the value of the bars as follows:

```
tickerDf['Momentum'] = tickerDf['Close'].diff(periods=10)
```

The data in the dataframe, and the last column is `Momentum`

```
2020-07-07  180.50  183.95  178.35  183.70  1418976 -4.73
2020-07-08  183.10  184.10  179.35  180.05   757800 7.08
2020-07-09  180.35  185.25  179.90  182.25   739061 -9.13
2020-07-10  181.10  181.70  177.65  177.70   933221 -2.65
2020-07-13  178.15  180.55  176.85  180.35  1088635 6.85
```

At the moment I just plot the column like this:

```
ax3.bar(s.index, s['Momentum'])
ax3.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax3.tick_params('x', labelrotation=45)
ax3.set_ylabel('Momentum')
```

But how do i plot the negativ momentum values red, and the positive green?

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50310048/6361531

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
clrs = ['red' if (x < 0) else 'green' for x in s['Momentum'] ]
ax3.bar(s.index, s['Momentum'], color=clrs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a color array and pass to the `bar` command:

```
colors = ['r' if m > 0 else 'g' for m in df.momentum]
df.plot.bar(y='momentum',color=colors, ax=ax3)
```

Output:

[image]